# Send email with .xlsx attachment using Google Apps Script (100 attachments sent as 100 separate emails to one email address)

Tags: google-apps-script, xlsx

I'm trying to send multiple excel files (.xlsx) as attachments to one email address in **separate** emails. For example, 100 excel files (.xlsx) would mean sending 100 individual emails. Is there any way I can automate this manual process using App Script? I'm still very new to App Script and I'm picturing something like below:

```js
function sendEmails() {
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
   var lr = ss.getLastRow();
   for i in range(lr): ## 
       var attachment_file =  ss.getRange(i, 2).getValue()
       MailApp.sendEmail("aa@example.com", "blank", "blank", {
         attachments: [attachment_file.getAs(MimeType.xlsx)]
            });
```

Is there a size limit to the xlsx file?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

#### Answer:

*Assuming your files are in your Drive and have unique names, you can do this with `DriveApp` and `MailApp`.*

#### Code Modifications:

```js
function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var lr = sheet.getLastRow();
  var fileNames = sheet.getRange(1, 2, lr, 1).getValues(); 
  var xlsxMT = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";

  for (var i = 0; i < lr; i++) { // modified
    let file = DriveApp.getFilesByName(fileNames[i][0]).next(); // modified
    MailApp.sendEmail("aa@example.com", "blank", "blank", {
      attachments: [file.getAs(xlsxMT)] // modified
    });
  }
}
```

**Modifications:**

- Retrieved all filenames outside the `for` loop to save on processing time.
- Obtained the file using the filename from the sheet using `DriveApp.getFilesByName()` Note: This assumes there is only one file in Drive with this name.
- Attached file using correct `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet` MIMEType.

#### References:

- [Class DriveApp | Apps Script | Google Developers - `getFilesByName(name)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfilesbynamename)
- [Class FileIterator | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file-iterator)
- [Class File | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file)