# Google Apps Script: How to getFileByID and set fileType as desired & more

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api, mime-types, google-forms

Listed below are some snippets from a script I'm writing that will send a spreadsheet over an order upload email via Google Form submission. I need to ensure the document I send (fileSheet) is properly formatted so that our team can perform an order upload through our OMS. Order uploads can be achieve via "Text (Tab Delimited)" fileType, which is done primarily by reviewing submitted data in excel then exporting as stated text file. I will note, I saw there is such thing as "text/tab-separated-values" - wouldn't hurt to send this in addition to the excel sheet to cut down on the tediousness put onto the order facilitators.

Unfortunately, I've found that although the datasheets uploaded thru the form are submitted as Datasheets, they are emailed as PDF's after being pulled from the upload drive by ID (Seen below via `DriveApp.getFileById(orderUploadResponse);`). I'm looking to work around this by pulling the Blob, setting the necessary parameters, then pushing this file to the facilitators. It would be favorable that the new file made is only created to be sent over email and not saved via Drive.

*(Note: The write-up below is my closest attempt)*

```
// Get key for datasheet
var orderUploadResponse = items[1].getResponse();

// Specify time ID
var timeFormatted = Utilities.formatDate(time, "CDT", "'MNL'-MMddyyyy-hhmm");

// Grab files from Google Drive for notification attachments
try {
var fileSheetByID = DriveApp.getFileById(orderUploadResponse);
var fileSheet = fileSheetByID.getBlob();
fileSheet.setContentType('application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet').setName(timeFormatted);
DriveApp.createFile(fileSheet);
}
catch (errXL) {
var fileSheet = DriveApp.getFileById(orderUploadResponse);
Logger.log("Datasheet (Blob Failed): " + errXL);
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the current issue with your script and your goal. In order to correctly understand your question, can I ask you about the detail of them? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Hi there Tanaike,

I am using a google form to accept a file upload. The file uploaded can only be sent over as a spreadsheet/excel file. I am recording what the document key/ID is via:

"var orderUploadResponse = items[1].getResponse();"

I'd like to find a way to take the uploaded document and send it over an email notification when the form is submitted. So far, I've been able to do everything except properly grab the spreadsheet and attach it to the email as an excel file. Currently, the file is uploading as a .pdf instead.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purpose of this script is to send an email on submission of a form, and to attach an uploaded Excel file to the email.

The script should be installed as an `onFormSubmit` trigger.

The recipient email must be inserted at line 28.

- Event Objects to identify the edited row
- The url for the uploaded file is passed to the linked spreadsheet; in this example it is in column C.

  - an example of the url is: `https://drive.google.com/open?id=1WAtFMx3IfxBO2zhFcAtx7PM5RXcSZJ7k`
  - using `indexOf`, the index position of "id=" can be established
  - using `substring`, the value of the file ID can be obtained.
- h/t @Ihopethisishelpfultoyou [Send email with .xlsx attachment using Google Apps Script (100 attachments sent as 100 separate emails to one email address)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63844903/1330560) for the syntax to send the email with the Excel file attachment.

---

```
/*
// this function to be an installable "onFormSubmit" trigger.
// the function sends an email 
// edit the recipient email address
*/
function sendEmail(e) {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Form responses 1")

var editedRow = e.range.rowStart
var lc = sheet.getLastColumn()
var dataRange = sheet.getRange(editedRow,1,1,lc)
// Logger.log("DEBUG: data range = "+dataRange.getA1Notation())
var data = dataRange.getValues()
var uploadURL = data[0][2]
var indexOfid = uploadURL.indexOf("id=");
var uploadID = uploadURL.substring(+indexOfid+3)
// Logger.log("DEBUG: url = "+uploadURL)
// Logger.log("DEBUG: id = "+uploadID)

// Specify time ID
var timeFormatted = Utilities.formatDate(new(Date), "CDT", "'MNL'-MMddyyyy-hhmm");


// Send an email with a file from Google Drive attached as a Excel.
var xlsxMT = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
var file = DriveApp.getFileById(uploadID);
GmailApp.sendEmail('<<insert recipient email>>', 'Attachment example', 'Please see the attached file.', {
      attachments: [file.getAs(xlsxMT)] // modified
    });
}
```